# Does IE7 incorrectly report the computed value of "position"?

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to find the closest "positioned" parent of an element using JavaScript. It works in every browser except IE7. The problem is that the `element.currentStyle['position']` is returning `static`, even though it is explicitly defined as `relative` in the stylesheet.

Can anyone shed some light on this and suggest a solution?

Edited to correct that IE7 is returning `static` even for relatively positioned elements.

Comment: All elements have a default position so basically you're trying to find the position value of the parent?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm using a recursive function to keep going up through the ancestors until it hits an element with a `position` that is not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
element.currentStyle.position //I tried it and worked for me
```

Comment: You're right. I can access the currentStyle.position property, but it's returning `static` even for a relatively positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using jQuery, this should work...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/MRdSx/

```
var count = 0;
while ($('.x').parents().eq(count).css('position') != 'relative') count++;
alert( $('.x').parents().eq(count).attr('id') );
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. I can get the `position` value, but it's reporting `static` instead of `relative`.

Comment: @mariachimike I tested in IE7 & IE6. The jQuery library may have better cross-browser support for this over raw Javascript.